# react className not defined in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I'm using a switch statement to render a component dynamically.
Anywhere the className attribute is used i get the error className is not defined and ingredient will always be null
if i remove the className attribute then it works fine

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from 'C:/Users/oluad/Desktop/my-burger-appp/src/Components/BugerIngredient/BurgerIngredient.css'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


 const BurgerIngredient = (props) => {

    let ingredient = null;

        switch(props.type){
            case('bread-bottom'):
            ingredient = <div className="dave"></div>;
            break;
            case('Bread-top'):
            ingredient =<div className={classes.BreadTop}></div>
            break
            case('Meat'):
            ingredient=<div>NO CLASSNAME !!!  WORKS FINE</div>
            break
            case('Cheese'):
            ingredient=<div className={classes.Cheese} ></div>
            break
            case('Salad'):
            ingredient=<div className={classes.Salad} ></div>
            break
            case('Bacon'):
            ingredient= <div className={classes.Bacon}></div>
            break
            case("bread-top"):
            ingredient=<div className={classes.BreadTop}>
                            <div className={classes.Seeds1}></div>
                            <div className={classes.seeds2}></div>
                        </div>
                        break
            default:
            ingredient=null
        }


   return  ingredient
}

BurgerIngredient.PropTypes = {
         type: PropTypes.string
     };

 export default BurgerIngredient
```

This is the css file im using BurgerIngredient.css
   Im using css modules

```
.BreadBottom {
    height: 13%;
    width: 80%;
    background: linear-gradient(#F08E4A, #e27b36);
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
    box-shadow: inset -15px 0 #c15711;
    margin: 2% auto;
}

.BreadTop {
    height: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    background: linear-gradient(#bc581e, #e27b36);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset -15px 0 #c15711;
    margin: 2% auto;
    position: relative;
}

.Seeds1 {
    width: 10%;
    height: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    left: 30%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 40%;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    box-shadow: inset -2px -3px #c9c9c9;
}

.Seeds1:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    left: -170%;
    top: -260%;
    border-radius: 40%;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    box-shadow: inset -1px 2px #c9c9c9;
  }

.Seeds1:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    left: 180%;
    top: -50%;
    border-radius: 40%;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    box-shadow: inset -1px -3px #c9c9c9;
  }

  .Seeds2 {
    width: 10%;
    height: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    left: 64%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 40%;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    box-shadow: inset -3px 0 #c9c9c9;
  }

  .Seeds2:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    left: 150%;
    top: -130%;
    border-radius: 40%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 3px #c9c9c9;
  }


.Meat {
    width: 80%;
    height: 8%;
    background: linear-gradient(#7f3608, #702e05);
    margin: 2% auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.Cheese {
    width: 90%;
    height: 4.5%;
    margin: 2% auto;
    background: linear-gradient(#f4d004, #d6bb22);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.Salad {
    width: 85%;
    height: 7%;
    margin: 2% auto;
    background: linear-gradient(#228c1d, #91ce50);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.Bacon {
    width: 80%;
    height: 3%;
    background: linear-gradient(#bf3813, #c45e38);
    margin: 2% auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't think your `classes` import should be an absolute path to somewhere on your computer. Try moving that file into an assets directory within your project. Does the className on 'bread-bottom' for "dave" work?

Comment: Agree,***classes*** impoted by relative path is better than absolute path

Comment: the className on 'bread-bottom' for "dave" does not work anywhere  the class name attributes used it does not work when I remove the class name Attribute it works as it is supposed to

Comment: Please attach `BurgerIngredient.css`, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how CSS files work, they don't export javascript objects. Import the CSS file so it is in scope and set the class names to match what is defined in your CSS. `classNames` prop is a string of class names, not an object.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'C:/Users/oluad/Desktop/my-burger-appp/src/Components/BugerIngredient/BurgerIngredient.css'; // just import the CSS file so it is in scope
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const BurgerIngredient = (props) => {
  let ingredient = null;

  switch(props.type){
    case('bread-bottom'):
      ingredient = <div className="dave"></div>;
      break;
    case('Bread-top'):
      ingredient = <div className="BreadTop"></div>;
      break;
    case('Meat'):
      ingredient = <div>NO CLASSNAME !!!  WORKS FINE</div>;
      break;
    case('Cheese'):
      ingredient = <div className"Cheese" ></div>;
      break;
    case('Salad'):
      ingredient = <div className="Salad" ></div>;
      break;
    case('Bacon'):
      ingredient = <div className="Bacon"></div>;
      break;
    case("bread-top"):
      ingredient = (
        <div className="BreadTop">
          <div className="Seeds1"></div>
          <div className="seeds2"></div>
        </div>
      );
      break;
    default:
      ingredient = null;
  }

  return ingredient;
}

BurgerIngredient.PropTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string
};

export default BurgerIngredient;
```

If you want to use a classes object like you were trying then you need to create a javascript file that exports an object defining key-value pairs that represent your classes and use correct [CSS-in-Javascript](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) syntax. This uses the react `style` prop though, and does not (I believe) allow for CSS pseudo-selectors (i.e. `::before`, `::after`), so you'd need to use some react component styling library, like `styled-components` that manages CSS-in-Javascript better.